# ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3491017035/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I've spent about 3 hours trying to find an answer to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to all of this.

According to the book I bought, I used "Visual Studio Code" to make a dockerfile. I named it Dockerfile and located it in my Projects folder

```
D:\Programing\Projects
```

when I use the docker build command in Ubuntu, I get the following

```
johnmark@DESKTOP-OJLA99O:/mnt/d/Programing/Projects$ docker build -t johnmark78/python-docker-tutorial:v1.0.0 .
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount4293617636/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

The book said to run the build docker command in the dir that had the Dockerfile in it. But the error I'm getting says no such file or directory?

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here...

Edit: OS info etc. Windows 10, i5-6600
dockerfile was made with Visual Studio Code v 1.83.0
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that oversite, as well as correcting the editing of my post

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the docker daemon is looking for a Dockerfile in your working directory to create your image. Please make sure that you have a file named Dockerfile (10 letters) in your working directory ($PWD/.).
Maybe you named it as Dockefile or Dockerfiel etc.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command from the directory where the dockerfile is located.

In this case assuming your docerkfile is sample.Dockerfile.

```
docker build -t johnmark78/python-docker-tutorial:v1.0.0 - < sample.Dockerfile
```

Comment: But why? Just specify the path to the file: `-f sample.Dockerfile`

Comment: I had this problem myself I tried using -f to explicitly specify the dockerfile bu that too resulted in the same error. I tried running this command and it worked. I think there was some issue related to build context.

Comment: But the Dockerfile is read before the build context comes into play. Can you actually reproduce the error again using `-f sample.Dockerfile`?